# Use the Fourier Series of $f(x)=x^2+1$ to find the sum of the series

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, fourier-series

I have found the Fourier Series of $f\left(x\right)=x^{2}+1$ on the interval $\left[-\pi, \pi\right]$ extended periodically to $\mathbb{R}$ to be
$$ f\left(x\right)=\dfrac{\pi^{2}}{3}+1+\sum^{\infty}_{n=1}\dfrac{4}{n}\left(-1\right)^{n}\cos\left(nx\right)$$

I now need to use this to find the sum of the series
$$\sum^{\infty}_{n=1}\dfrac{1}{n^2}$$

I understand that this will involve rearranging f(x) but I am not sure how.

Comment: the Fourier series of $x^2+1$, a non-periodic function ?

Comment: Saying "the fourier series of $x^2+1$" is really meaingless, since that function is not $2\pi$ periodic. You mean the fourier series of $x^2+1$ _on_ the interval $[-\pi,\pi]$, or on the interval $[0,2\pi]$ or something. Anyway: _Parseval_.

Comment: given the $\pi^2/3+1$ it is $[-\pi,\pi]$, and the fact there is no $\sin$ approves that

Comment: Looks like you read part of the comments but not all. You can do this using _Parseval_.